# Disable hardware BING button in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've recently bought a HTC Windows Phone 8X.
Pretty nice device so far. But the sensor-keys on the bottom of the device are very sensitive and touching them accidentally (what happens quite often) is pretty annoying.

Does some way exist to disable them? (with help of some setting or an application running in the background)

Thanks for help.

Comment: Not a programming question, therefore off topic.

Comment: Why? Maybe it can be disabled by running an application in the background?

Comment: I think such questions belong here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: then ask about HOW to write such an application. we're not here to search the MS App store for you. Just don't ask for someone to give you the code and teach you how to get an app signed and into the store. You'd have to ask specific details about something in the code.

Comment: Marc, if you don't want to help, why don't you just ignore my question?

Comment: Thanks to the hint of Abbas, I found the answer here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-any-way-to-disable-some-of-the-hardware-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The only button that can have it's behaviour modified by any application is the back button.

Comment: Could you please provide any link to WP documentation?